# How do you use jQuery to find an element by its html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a way to use jQuery to get the first empty div with a certain class. I tried this:

```
$(".box[html='']").
```

but it didn't work. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('.box:empty:first')
```

http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

Comment: add `.eq(0)` since he asked for the first one and +1 for this

Comment: @mVChr Yes, I noticed. I used `:first`

Answer (score 7):

That syntax only works for attributes. For HTML contents, you can use `.filter()`:

```
$('.box').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).html()) === '';
}).eq(0);
```

**Edit**: The problem with `:empty` is that line-breaks and spaces are *not* empty. So:

```
<div> </div>
<div>
</div>
```

... won't match.

Comment: +1 and please use `return $.trim(this.innerHTML) === '';`. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

You html:

```
<div class="empty"></div>
<div class="empty"></div>
```

your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".empty:empty:first").html("JJJJ");

});
```

Check this

http://jsfiddle.net/y4Ef2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var boxEq;
$('div.box').each(function(i,obj){
  if (boxEq === void(0)) {
    if ($(obj).html() === '') {
      boxEq = i;
      break;
    }
  }
});

// this is your div
$('div.box').eq(boxEq);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('.box').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().length == 0)
    //box is empty
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.box:empty").eq(0)
```

added `.eq(0)` since you said ***first*** empty